# How to make a window fullscreen in customtkinter?

Tags: python, customtkinter

`Tkinter` has this method:

```
window_name.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
```

and `customtkinter`?

I haven't found anything but

```
geometry(f"{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}")
```

However when I grab screen size and put as WIDTH & HEIGHT the screen does change the size but does not go full size, I mean it is always shifted to the right so the windows leaves the margin on the left and top and the part of the window goes out of the screen to the right.

Comment: You can't use `wm_attributes` on ctk windows?

Comment: I didn't know I could, I could not find any documentation about this on customtkinter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions you have to call to setup full screen (at least on Linux).

```py
    self.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    self.state('normal')  # This call is appears to be necessary to make the app actually go full screen.
```

This works on customtkinter v5.2

Answer (score -1):

If you want to **maximize** your Window use:

```
root = CTk()
root.after(0, lambda:root.state('zoomed'))
root.mainloop()
```

If you want **real Fullscreen**, use this:

```
root = ctk.CTk()
root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.mainloop()
```